# RSpec 3.1 undefined method `feature' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I´m going through the rather painful upgrade to RSpec 3.1. I have several feature specs which worked in RSpec 2.99 that raise:

```
undefined method `feature' for main:Object
```

I noticed that I have to use `RSpec.describe` in my other specs since they are are no longer attached to the main object. What would the equivalent call for feature be?

In my features I require 'rails_helper'

```
require 'rails_helper'
feature 'Facebook Authentiation' do
  ...
end
```

*spec/rails_helper.rb*

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rails/application'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

*spec/spec_helper.rb*
#

```
 See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|

  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is recommended.
  # For more details, see:
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
  #   - http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#new__config_option_to_disable_rspeccore_monkey_patching
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
end
```

*Gemfile*

```
# ...
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
end

# ...
group :test do
  # ...
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.3'
end
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It looks like your forgot to require capybara at your spec/rails_helper.rb

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

Also you can try to remove this line:

```
config.disable_monkey_patching!
```

Or check if capybara adds feature method to Rspec namespace:

```
RSpec.feature "My feature" do
  ...
end
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that i already tested and Capybara was defined.

Comment: Thanks,`RSpec.feauture` works with `config.disable_monkey_patching!` and disabling `config.disable_monkey_patching!` allows `feature` as in older versions of RSpec.

Answer (score 15):

I've faced the same issue with rails 4.2 even though I've had

`require 'capybara/rspec'` in `rails_helper.rb`

and

`require 'spec_helper'` in feature spec.

**Solution** is to `require 'rails_helper'` in feature spec as well.

Comment: You need to require `rails_helper` in most specs which actually use the rails framework. The whole idea between splitting the config files is that you use the faster loading `spec_helper` for plain old ruby objects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had the

```
require "spec_helper"
```

line lower in rails_helper.rb.

When I moved it at the top, everything went back to normal.

For your reference, my rails_helper.rb first lines now are:

```
require "spec_helper"
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require "rspec/rails"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the following in my problem which is a combination of previous answers:

**spec/features/visitors/navigation_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.feature 'Navigation links', :devise do
...
end
```

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
config.disable_monkey_patching = false
```